# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.opencv.imgcodecs.Imgcodecs.imread_0(Ljava/lang/String;I)J

Tags: java, opencv

I'm trying to do some operations with a Matrix in Java using opencv. I'm using Netbeans IDE.

The problem happens when I try to declare a new matrix with the constructor, then I get the following error in the console:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.opencv.imgcodecs.Imgcodecs.imread_0(Ljava/lang/String;I)J
at org.opencv.imgcodecs.Imgcodecs.imread_0(Native Method)
at org.opencv.imgcodecs.Imgcodecs.imread(Imgcodecs.java:93)
at imagecomparator.Mini.compareFeature(Mini.java:62)
at imagecomparator.Mini.main(Mini.java:37)
```

Java Result: 1

My Code is as the following :

```
public static int compareFeature(String filename1, String filename2) throws IOException {
    int retVal = 0;
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.library.path")); 
    System.load( "C:\\Windows\\System32\\opencv_java310.dll" );
  // Load images to compare

    System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME); 
    Mat img1  = Imgcodecs.imread(filename1, Imgcodecs.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
    Mat img2  = Imgcodecs.imread(filename2, Imgcodecs.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);

 }
```

Is there anything I am doing wrong to cause this error?

Comment: Are you using the same version of the library at compile time vs runtime?

Comment: Yes. I am using the same version of the library at compile time vs runtime

Answer (score 3):

I had the same error because I didn't load the opencv .dll file first.
Check that `System.load("opencv dll directory")` has been executed before you call your code.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to set environment variable to:

```
C:\opencv\build\java\x64
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are loading the right opencv native library version (corresponding to Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME).